# Load a view controller at the end of a countdown

Tags: cocoa-touch, nstimer

I want to load a new view controller at the end of a countdown that uses an `NSTimer`. Should I use a notification to do that?

Comment: Do you need the ability to cancel the timer?

Comment: @Eimantas  No i can cancel the Timer Using invalidate. But the problem is that After Invalidate i want to load another ViewController from my Current ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

you can post an notification after you call invalidate to the timer.

make the current viewcontroller listen to the notification to push to another viewcontroler

Comment: I have used this below code.  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rightnavbuttonpressed:) name:@"SomeEvent" object:nil];

 - (void)rightnavbuttonpressed:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // handle event
    NSLog(@"You have called me! Ha Ha...");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"medalstosplashscreen" sender:sender];

}
But the Code is not working. Please check and guide me if i am committing any mistake.

Comment: can u reach to this line > NSLog(@"You have called me! Ha Ha...");
if not then check the code that post the notification, if it can received the notification then check the method you push the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Start another method on [self performeSelector after delay] with the same countdown.